# Prove that set of all step function L_{step} is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am supposed to prove that set of all step function  $$ L_{step}$$ is a vector space.

I undestand, that I have to verify it for all conditions of vector space, but I do not know how to write it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You essentially need to check that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. The latter should be plain; for the former, note that you are done if you can show that two step functions $\varphi=\sum_i a_i\mathbb{1}_{A_i}, \psi=\sum_i b_i\mathbb{1}_{B_i}$, where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$, can be written as $\varphi=\sum_i a'_i\mathbb{1}_{C_i},\psi=\sum_ib'_i\mathbb{1}_{C_i}$, where the $C_i$'s are the same. How can you do that?

Comment: @Cristofer something like this?  $$(\sum _{i}a_{i}1_{Ai}+\sum _{i}b_{i}1_{Bi})(s)=\sum _{i}a_{i}1_{Ai}(s)+\sum _{i}b_{i}1_{Bi}(s)$$

Comment: That is just the definition of sum in what you call $L_{step}$. What you need to prove is that, if $\varphi,\psi$ are step functions, $\varphi+\psi$ (defined, as you wrote, by $(\varphi+\psi)(s):=\varphi(s)+\psi(s)$ for all $s$) also is. Now, this is clear if $\varphi=\sum_i a_i1_{C_i},\psi=\sum_i b_i1_{C_i}$ with the same $C_i$'s, for $\varphi+\psi$ is just $\sum_i (a_i+b_i)1_{C_i}$. The only question is then: is this always the case, in the sense that you can choose representations for $\varphi,\psi$ involving the same sets? (Hint: take intersections $A_i\cap B_j$)

Comment: @CristoferVillani Is intersection  $$A_{i}\cap B_{j}$$ =0 if i is not equal to j? So if interals are not the same , it is not cllosed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: Not at all. What I wanted to point out is that, if $\varphi=\sum_i a_i1_{A_i},\psi=\sum_j b_j1_{B_j}$, the equalities $\varphi=\sum_{i,j} a_i1_{A_i\cap B_j}$ and $\psi=\sum_{i,j} b_j1_{A_i\cap B_j}$ also hold, thus giving you that $\varphi+\psi$ is still a step-function by what was said before. Still, this is a really visual argument: I'd suggest you to check that you understood what a step function is, for (no offense!) I suspect you did not.